Proof that the nonzero rows of a row echelon form matrix are linearly independent
I'm following a proof of the theorem that the nonzero rows of a row echelon form matrix are linearly independent by Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra. One of the assumptions made in this proof doesn't seem right.
Anyway, the proof goes like this.
Proof:
Let $M_{m\times n}$ be a matrix. Now, let $\vec{\alpha}_1,...,\vec{\alpha}_m$ be the rows of this matrix. It is to be shown that, for the following equation, $c_1,...,c_m = 0$:
$$c_1\vec{\alpha}_1+...+c_m\vec{\alpha}_m = \vec{0}$$
$$c_1\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{1,1}\\\vdots\\\alpha_{1,n}
\end{bmatrix}+...+c_m\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{m,1}\\\vdots\\\alpha_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix} = \vec{0}$$
Here, $\alpha_{m,n}$ is the $m^{th}$ row of the $n^{th}$ column of the matrix.
$$c_1\alpha_{1,1}+...+c_m\alpha_{m,1} = 0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$c_1\alpha_{1,n}+...+c_m\alpha_{m,n} = 0$$
Now, in echelon form, $\alpha_{2,1} = ... = \alpha_{m,1} = 0$. Hence, the first equation just becomes $c_1\alpha_{1,1} = 0$. Now, the author says that $\alpha_{1,1}\neq0$ since it is a leading variable. Thus, $c_1 = 0$. A similar line of reasoning would be used for $n=2$. Here, $\alpha_{3,2} = ... = \alpha_{m,2} = 0$. Then, $c_1\alpha_{1,2}+c_2\alpha_{2,2} = 0$. Since $c_1 = 0$ and $\alpha_{2,2} \neq 0$, $c_2 = 0$.
But how does echelon form require that $\alpha_{1,1}$ and $\alpha_{2,2}$ don't be zero. For example, isn't this a row echelon form matrix?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 4 & 9 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
For the above matrix, $\alpha_{2,2} = 0$. But isn't this still row echelon form?

To prove $c_1 = 0$ you do not necessarily look at the first column, you look at the first nonzero column, so the first entry is nonzero and all others are zero.
Similarly, to prove $c_2 = 0$ you do not look at the second column, you need to look at the column where the leading entry of the second row is. If $\ell_2$ is the index of this column, then we have $\alpha_{2, \ell_2} \neq 0$ and $\alpha_{3, \ell_2} = \dots = \alpha_{n, \ell_2} = 0$. Taking into account $c_1 = 0$, the equation
$$c_1 \alpha_{1, \ell_2} + c_2 \alpha_{2, \ell_2} + \dots + c_n \alpha_{n, \ell_2} = 0$$
implies $c_2 = 0$.
I looked at the book (Lemma 1.III.2.5) and the proof does exactly this. The author denotes by $\ell_i$ the column of the leading entry in the $i$-th row.
